# BigInsights on cloud - Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain not found

Tags: ibm-cloud, biginsights, biginsight-examples

I'm trying to execute the [spark oozie example](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/BigInsights-on-Apache-Hadoop/tree/oozie_spark/examples/OozieWorkflowSparkGroovy) on the [oozie_spark branch](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/BigInsights-on-Apache-Hadoop/tree/oozie_spark) against a BigInsights for Apache Hadoop basic cluster.

The workflow.xml looks like this:

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='SparkWordCount'>
 <start to='spark-node' />
  <action name='spark-node'>
   <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <master>${master}</master>
    <name>Spark-Wordcount</name>
    <class>org.apache.spark.examples.WordCount</class>
    <jar>${hdfsSparkAssyJar},${hdfsWordCountJar}</jar>
    <spark-opts>--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Diop.version=4.2.0.0</spark-opts>
    <arg>${inputDir}/FILE</arg>
    <arg>${outputDir}</arg>
   </spark>
   <ok to="end" />
   <error to="fail" />
  </action>
  <kill name="fail">
   <message>Workflow failed, error
    message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]
   </message>
  </kill>
 <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

The configuration.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>master</name>
        <value>local</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>queueName</name>
        <value>default</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>user.name</name>
        <value>default</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>nameNode</name>
        <value>default</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>jobTracker</name>
        <value>default</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>jobDir</name>
        <value>/user/snowch/test</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>inputDir</name>
        <value>/user/snowch/test/input</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>outputDir</name>
        <value>/user/snowch/test/output</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hdfsWordCountJar</name>
        <value>/user/snowch/test/lib/OozieWorkflowSparkGroovy.jar</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>oozie.wf.application.path</name>
        <value>/user/snowch/test</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hdfsSparkAssyJar</name>
        <value>/iop/apps/4.2.0.0/spark/jars/spark-assembly.jar</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

However, the error I see in the Yarn logs is:

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], exception invoking main(), java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain not found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runSubtask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:380)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.runTask(LocalContainerLauncher.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler.access$200(LocalContainerLauncher.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalContainerLauncher$EventHandler$1.run(LocalContainerLauncher.java:230)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
    ... 13 more
```

I've looked for SparkMain in spark-assembly:

```
$ hdfs dfs -get /iop/apps/4.2.0.0/spark/jars/spark-assembly.jar
$ jar tf spark-assembly.jar | grep -i SparkMain
```

And here:

```
$ jar tf /usr/iop/4.2.0.0/spark/lib/spark-examples-1.6.1_IBM_4-hadoop2.7.2-IBM-12.jar | grep SparkMain
```

I've seen another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410831/example-oozie-job-works-from-hue-but-not-from-command-line-sparkmain-not-found) similar to this one, but this question is specifically about BigInsights on cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved with:

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.use.system.libpath</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

I should have RTFM properly.